# MY React Web Page Does not work in an iframe

Tags: reactjs, iframe, react-hooks

I've build a web app on react and used react hooks for my forms.

However it is not working when the web application is embedded within another application.

The forms shown to have none of the inputs filled. may i know why ? (Althought from the view, the forms are being filled up).

It works individually if not rendered in an iframe.